# How to ignore some tags (B,I,STRONG) in the response?

Tags: xml, json, xpath, yql

I try to scrape some website with YQL (for a Appcelerator Titanium mobile app).

The data I need is within an A tag, but it's formatted:

```
<a href="...">
     <strong>Drugs</strong> and Culture</font>
</a>
```

so, when I run query like:

```
select * from html where  url='...'  and xpath="//table[2]/tr/td[2]//a"
```

I get:

```
 {"strong": "Drugs", "content": "\n and Culture"}
```

I need YQL to ignore those "strong" tags and respond with text value:

```
{content: "Drugs and Culture"}
```

Do You have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I don't know YQL, but a pure XPath expression that produces the wanted result is:**

```
normalize-space(//table[2]/tr/td[2]//a)
```